# receiving JSON object in java RESTful Web Services (javax.ws..rs.*) Jersey

Tags: java, json, web-services, node.js, jersey

I am having problems with getting a json contentType through to glassfish server where I have java restful web service setup.

I POST from Node.js with needle :

```
var options = {
    json: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
}

needle.post(base_url+'priorityList/',priorityList,options, function(err, resp, body){
});
```

and receive with jersey:

```
@POST
@Path("/priorityList/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public JSONArray priorityList(JSONObject incomingJsonString)throws IOException {
}
```

and it gives me  this error on the glassfish server:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[com.mycompany.recommenderenginejava.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.mycompany.recommenderenginejava.ApplicationConfig threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.Unr`enter code here`ecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "{"categories":["golf","banks"]}" (Class com.mycompany.recommenderenginejava.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@4c0db744; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: com.mycompany.recommenderenginejava.JSONObject["{"categories":["golf","banks"]}"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
```

this looks like it should be in correct format, I dint understand, and have tried 1000 things to get it working.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to post up com.mycompany.recommenderenginejava.JSONObject if you want specific advice but the answer is that the JSON doesn't match the class you're trying to parse it into.  The JSON has a field ("categories") that isn't present as a public field or setter in the class definition.

Comment: this is the JSONObject class I use: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I see what you mean, that when I try to import the JSON object into JSON Object I cannot unless there is a constructor int he JSONObject which supports the POST data... doesnt @consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) help with anything

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way you're doing it, but I am familiar with Jackson.  Have you tried using your won POJO instead of a JSON object?

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem with making my own class which had attributes for each of the names in the JSON I was sending. I thought there would have been some default implementation for JSON in jersey but making your own class works too... I really like javascript and its var type :)

Comment: Glad it worked.  That's the standard way of doing it and you'll end up with much cleaner code because of it.  Please accept the answer.